# Probability question regarding sequential events

Tags: probability

> There are 3 players $A, B, C$ and they throw a die sequentially until somebody wins. $A$ wins if he scores either $5$ or $6$. $B$ wins if the die is an even number and $C$ wins if he scores an odd number.
>
> Find the probability that player $C$ throws the dice at least 3 times.

Solution:

Let $P_i =$ {Player $P$ wins after throwing the die the i-th time}

$D =$ {Player $C$ throws the die at least 3 times}.

$\bar D =${Player $C$ throws the die 2 times at most}.

- $C$ throws the die exactly $0$ times, which is:

$A_1\cup \bar{A}_1B_1$

- $C$ throws the die exactly $1$ time, which means that:
  Player C wins during the first round or Player A or Player B win the second round, i.e:

$\bar{A}_1 \bar{B}_1 C_1 \cup \bar{A}_1 \bar{B}_1 \bar{C}_1 A_1 \cup\bar{A}_1 \bar{B}_1 \bar{C}_1 \bar{A}_2B_2$

The same argument is for the third case, where Player C throws the die exactly 2 times.

However, the answer of the textbook is that for the event $\bar{D}$ when we have:

$
\bar{D} = A_1 + \bar{A}_1 B_1 +\bar{A}_1\bar{B}_1C_1 +\bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}C_2 + \bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}\bar{C}_2 A_3 + \bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}\bar{C}_2 \bar{A}_3B_3
$

Why is that the case?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just compute $\left (P(\bar A)\times P(\bar B)\times P(\bar C)\right)^2\times \left (P(\bar A)\times P(\bar B)\right)=P(\bar A)^3\times P(\bar B)^3\times P(\bar C)^2$

Comment: why is it not?  {Player C throws the die fewer than 3 times} = {C throws the die exactly 0 times}  + {C throws the die exactly 1 time}  + {Player C throws the die exactly 2 times}

Comment: Note: I think the rules are not clear.  I am reading it as "each player throws the die in sequence.  A given player can only win if it is their turn. and the rules for each player's victory are as stated."  Is this correct?

Comment: @lulu Yes, I think this is what the book means. Each player can win only during his turn. But even in that case, shouldn't we considerable as favourable event that Player C will throw the die once if A or B wins the second round? In the textbook solution, I think this is overlooked.

Comment: @MoonKnight So, do you agree with my logic?

Comment: Well, I'd read it as saying the game stopped once somebody won.  Easy to compute, either way.

Comment: @Lulu I do agree that it's not a very difficult problem. I'm trying to follow the textbook's logic. But I can't seem to find the error in my logic, because I can see  the book seems to miss some of my terms.

Comment: Well, first we have to agree on a set of rules.  Following my choice (which of course might be wrong) do you agree with the answer I provided?

Comment: Note:  I find it hard to read what you wrote.  As I read it, your events $D,\overline D$ intersect non-trivially (when $C$ throws exactly $3$ times). I was using the bar to denote complement, as I assumed you were.

Comment: @lulu Regarding, your first answer, the first parenthesis means that no one wins during the first two rounds and the second parenthesis is that during the third throw neither A nor B wins. So C will have to throw the die for the third time. So, isn't this the probability that C will throw the die exactly 3 times?

Comment: No.  $C$ might lose again, in which case the game continues.

Comment: @lulu Oh yes, definitely.

Comment: @thanasissdr oh yes. you are right. I did not read the book's solution carefully enough

Answer (score 0):

Lulu is definitely correct about the best way to answer this. The book's method is needlessly complicated. But let's examine it anyway:

$$\bar{D} = A_1 + \bar{A}_1 B_1 +\bar{A}_1\bar{B}_1C_1 +\bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}C_2 + \bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}\bar{C}_2 A_3 + \bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}\bar{C}_2 \bar{A}_3B_3$$

We are calculating all the ways that $C$ doesn't throw $3$ times - i.e., all the ways that the game can end before his third throw.

- $A_1 = A$ wins on the first throw.
- $\bar A_1B_1 = B$ wins his first throw (after $A$ loses his)
- $\bar{A}_1\bar{B}_1C_1 = C$ wins his first throw (after $A, B$ both lose).
- $\bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}C_2 = C$ wins his 2nd throw.
- $\bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}\bar{C}_2 A_3 = A$ wins on his 3rd throw.
- $\bar{A}_1 \bar{B_1}\bar{C}_1\bar{A}_2 \bar{B_2}\bar{C}_2 \bar{A}_3B_3 = B$ wins on his 3rd throw.

Note that there is an obvious jump in the progression: the contributions from $A$ or $B$ winning on their 2nd throw are missing.

So the answer to your question "why is that the case?" is: Because your book is wrong.

Probably somebody skipped a couple terms accidently while formatting this horrendous equation.